# why does column trades.item_id not exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, has-many-through, belongs-to

I have a relationship model in which two Users can enter into a Trade for the exchange of two Items.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :owned_items, class_name: "Item"
 has_many :trades_received, class_name: "Trade", through: :owned_items, source: :trades
 has_many :trades
 has_many :wanted_items, class_name: "Item", through: :trades, source: :item
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
 has_many :trades, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :trade_requesters, through: :trades
 has_many :trade_recipients, through: :trades
end

class Trade < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :trade_requester, class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :trade_recipient, class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :wanted_item, class_name: "Item", foreign_key: :wanted_item_id
 belongs_to :collateral_item, class_name: "Item", foreign_key: :collateral_item_id
end
```

The migration on my Trades table looks like this:

```
create_table :trades do |t|
 t.belongs_to :trade_requester
 t.belongs_to :trade_recipient
 t.belongs_to :wanted_item
 t.belongs_to :collateral_item
end
```

The stack trace leads to a helper method I'm using to list all Trade requests. That line says `@trades = current_user.trades_received.requested.count`, and then on down to the model association on User where `has_many :owned_items, class_name: "Item"`. From my understanding, it looks like the `trades_received` method, which is called `through: :owned_items` and `source: :trades` should be referencing the `:wanted_item_id` foreign key in the migration. But it is not. It works if I create a migration to add `item_id`, but a Trade needs two items, and so I've split it up into the two `wanted_item` and `collateral_item` associations. How do I set that User association up so that it references the Item that is being requested by another User? Should Items `has_many :trades`, the way I have it, or should Items `belongs_to :trades`?

Full error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column trades.item_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...LECT COUNT(*) FROM "trades" INNER JOIN "items" ON "trades"."...
                                                         ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "trades" INNER JOIN "items" ON "trades"."item_id" = "items"."id" WHERE "items"."user_id" = $1 AND "trades"."approved" IS NULL
```

tldr: I need to track a bunch of complex `has_many :through` associations, I don't think my data model is correct, and need help understanding why. Thank you.

Comment: `User has_many :trades_received`. So it should be `current_user.trades_receiveds`. Probably better to change it to `received_trades`. And what is your `#requested` method like? Which exact line gives you the error?

Comment: `requested` is a scope, and it's just `scope :requested, -> { where(approved: nil) }`. My error comes from a helper that I'm using in my header, and goes down to the User model's `:trades_received` association. @unkmas suggested that it's caused by the fact that my setup had no direct link between Trade and Item.

Comment: @sabaeus can you paste database schema file

Comment: @sabaeus  add this  t.belongs_to :trade    in  migration.

Comment: @krishnar add it to the Trades migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting up two `has_many :through` relationship between `User` and `Item`, with `Trade` as the join table for both. You got some relationship confused. Here is a setup based on your migration:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :received_trades, class_name: "Trade", foreign_key: "trade_recipient"
 has_many :requested_trades, class_name: "Trade", foreign_key: "trade_requester"
 has_many :collateral_items, through: :received_trades
 has_many :wanted_items, through: :requested_trades
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :collateral_items, class_name: "Trade", foreign_key: "collateral_item"
 has_many :wanted_items, class_name: "Trade", foreign_key: "wanted_item"
 has_many :trade_requesters, through: :wanted_items
 has_many :trade_recipients, through: :collateral_items
end

class Trade < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :trade_requester, class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :trade_recipient, class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :wanted_item, class_name: "Item"
 belongs_to :collateral_item, class_name: "Item"
end

##migration
create_table :trades do |t|
 t.belongs_to :trade_requester
 t.belongs_to :trade_recipient
 t.belongs_to :wanted_item
 t.belongs_to :collateral_item
end
```

Some explanation:

```
Item has_many :collateral_item  ## item_id in table collateral_items
Item has_many :collateral_item, class_name: "Trade", foreign_key: "collateral_item"
##collateral_item_id in trades table.
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. Question though: I thought foreign_keys were only supposed to be on the `belongs_to` side of a relationship?

Comment: Both `has_many` and `belongs_to` has the `foreign_key` option. It's used when the foreign key does not follow the ActiveRecord convention (i.e. association name + "_id"), which is the case for the `has_many` relationships here.

Comment: But why would i put it on one side over another?

Comment: You need to use it when Rails can't infer the correct foreign key. Say if you can have something like `belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "trade_requester"` i n `Trade` instead of what we have there. There's no one way to do it.

Comment: I think there's a problem with this. The `collateral_item` and `wanted_item` associations on User each go through `trades` but `trades` isn't an association in `User`. Furthermore, `trades` would need to reference two foreign keys - `trade_requester` and `trade_recipient`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Trade has two belongs_to with User with the correct foreign keys. What is the problem?

Comment: `through: :trades` doesn't work unless you explicitly declare `has_many :trades` on a model. If that hasn't been declared, you get an error that says the trades association doesn't exist. I did manage to make it work by doing this - `through: :received_trades` and `through: :requested_trades`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well. The problem is here:

```
has_many :trades, dependent: :destroy
```

And in your `Trade` model:

```
belongs_to :wanted_item, ...
belongs_to :collateral_item, ..
```

Rails cannot handle this automatically.

You need to do one of this steps (depending on what you need in your app):

If you need separate associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trades_received, class_name: "Trade", through: :owned_items, source: :wantable_trades
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wanted_trades, class_name: 'Trade', inverse_of: :wanted_item, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :collateral_trades, class_name: 'Trade', inverse_of: :collateral_item, dependent: :destroy
end
```

If you need all trades as single association:

Well, you will have a pain in the ass :) In this case you should either select associations manually, or rethink your data model.

Comment: what do you mean by "select associations manually, or rethink your data model?" Are `:wanted_trades` and `:trades_received` not separate associations? also, why do you have `:wanted_trades` twice in the Item model? wouldn't that just reference the same item twice?

Comment: @sabaeus sorry, I accidentally discarded edits. Updated my answer.
Item cannot just `have many trades` because, there is no direct link from trade to item (`item_id` or whatever). So you have to separate associations. If you want to select all trades for item you have to either selct them manually (`Trade.where("wanted_item_id =? or collateral_item_id =?", self.id`) or change your db schema.

Comment: Ohhhh, and so `inverse_of` creates that link? Wow, that finally makes sense. Thank you! I'm confused about the other thing, though. Are you saying that manual selection is unadvisable, or likely to be a pain? I only ask because my initial post had multiple associations for Trade, but your answer said "if you need all trades as a single association"

Comment: It's almost always is a pain. When in the feature you will need to add some additional logic - filters, new data to view, whatever - it will be a pain to do so.

Comment: I'm confused by the idea that there could be a way of doing this that would not at some point require manual selection. Is there anything I could read that would help me understand?

Comment: @sabaeus sorry, but i cannot help you there :(